# Can't open an URL in Python without opened it in browser first

Tags: python, url, browser

I want to make a bot that tweet NBA Scores every day. So I need to get the NBA Scores from the stats.nba website every day. 
The problem is if I don't click on the JSON link and access it with my browser before trying to open it in my code it doesn't work. There is a new link every day for the matchs of the night.

Does anyone know how to solve that ? 
Thank you

Comment: Could you provide the python code you used to access the API?

Comment: @JanisJansen even a simple `f = requests.get(url)
print(f.text)` doesn't work if I don't open the url first in a browser.

Comment: To me that sounds a lot like an API/Authorization or CORS issue. You could double-check for the API usage requirements if any form of authorization is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be interesting to see your code and figure out why it needs to be opened in the browser first, but if that really is the case:

Just open it with webbrowser first:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)
# rest of your logic below.
```

This will open the url in your systems default browser.

You could also check if you're missing some flags such as allowing for redirects or if you need an user-agent (so it looks like you're visiting from a browser)

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, allow_redirects = True)
response.raise_for_status()
content = response.text
```

Comment: Thank you it does work with that (if I wait long enough for the browser to open the page) but I would like a solution that does not open a new tab in a browser, if I plan to host my python code in a server I don't think that would work.
even a simple 
`f = requests.get(url) 
print(f.text)`
 doesn't work if I don't open the url first in a browser.